# Unsetting local variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

There are a couple of examples of this behavior in Code Igniter framework - creating a variable at the beginning of a method, working with it, and before the end of the method, unsetting this variable.

Why do they unset them? What's the point? As far as I know, local variables die at the end of the method anyways.

Code igniter, from the session class (see last lines):

```
function sess_read()
{
    // Fetch the cookie
    $session = $this->CI->input->cookie($this->sess_cookie_name);

    // No cookie?  Goodbye cruel world!...
    if ($session === FALSE)
    {
        log_message('debug', 'A session cookie was not found.');
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Decrypt the cookie data
    if ($this->sess_encrypt_cookie == TRUE)
    {
        $session = $this->CI->encrypt->decode($session);
    }
    else
    {
        // encryption was not used, so we need to check the md5 hash
        $hash    = substr($session, strlen($session)-32); // get last 32 chars
        $session = substr($session, 0, strlen($session)-32);

        // Does the md5 hash match?  This is to prevent manipulation of session data in userspace
        if ($hash !==  md5($session.$this->encryption_key))
        {
            log_message('error', 'The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.');
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Unserialize the session array
    $session = $this->_unserialize($session);

    // Is the session data we unserialized an array with the correct format?
    if ( ! is_array($session) OR ! isset($session['session_id']) OR ! isset($session['ip_address']) OR ! isset($session['user_agent']) OR ! isset($session['last_activity']))
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Is the session current?
    if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Does the IP Match?
    if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE AND $session['ip_address'] != $this->CI->input->ip_address())
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Does the User Agent Match?
    if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE AND trim($session['user_agent']) != trim(substr($this->CI->input->user_agent(), 0, 120)))
    {
        $this->sess_destroy();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Is there a corresponding session in the DB?
    if ($this->sess_use_database === TRUE)
    {
        $this->CI->db->where('session_id', $session['session_id']);

        if ($this->sess_match_ip == TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('ip_address', $session['ip_address']);
        }

        if ($this->sess_match_useragent == TRUE)
        {
            $this->CI->db->where('user_agent', $session['user_agent']);
        }

        $query = $this->CI->db->get($this->sess_table_name);

        // No result?  Kill it!
        if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
        {
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is there custom data?  If so, add it to the main session array
        $row = $query->row();
        if (isset($row->user_data) AND $row->user_data != '')
        {
            $custom_data = $this->_unserialize($row->user_data);

            if (is_array($custom_data))
            {
                foreach ($custom_data as $key => $val)
                {
                    $session[$key] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Session is valid!
    $this->userdata = $session;
    unset($session);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Can you bother showing us the code instead of writing this story?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030600/php-whats-the-benefit-of-unsetting-variables....perhaps this might help you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) destroys the specified variables. but `unset()` does not free the memory consumed by the PHP script, it does free it for use by the PHP script itself. It does not force immediate memory freeing. PHP's garbage collector will do it when it see fits - by intention as soon, as those CPU cycles aren't needed anyway, or as late as before the script would run out of memory, whatever occurs first.

So, if you are creating a variable of 10M of size 10 times in a loop and unsetting (or rewriting) it at the end of the loop, the memory consumption should be as low as 10M + all other variables by the end of the loop.

Read more

[What's better at freeing memory with PHP: unset() or $var = null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null)

[why UNSET and NULL are working in different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647795/why-unset-and-null-are-working-in-different-ways)